# What are the relations between classes "type" and "object"?

Tags: python, python-3.x

1. The class `type` is an instance of itself, i.e. `type` is a metaclass of itself. How can we define a class
   which is an instance of itself?

   ```
   >>> type(type)
   <class 'type'>
   ```

   How can `type` be an instance of both `object` and `type`, i.e. how can `object` and `type` both be metaclasses of `type`?

   ```
   >>> builtins.isinstance(type, object)
   True
   ```
2. How can `object` and `type` be an instance of each other, i.e. how can they be a metaclass of each other?

   ```
   >>> type(object)
   <class 'type'>
   >>> builtins.isinstance(type, object)
   True
   >>> builtins.isinstance(object, type)
   True
   ```
3. How can `object` and `type` be an instance of each other, while `type`
   is an subclass of `object`?

   ```
   >>> builtins.issubclass(type, object)
   True
   >>> builtins.issubclass(object, type)
   False
   ```

Comment: Best explanation I could find for the perceived ambiguity: http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2012/03/30/python-objects-types-classes-and-instances-a-glossary

Comment: No matter what you put as the first input, if "object" or "type" are the second input to isinstance, it will return true.  Everything is an object and a type, including object and type.  Object is the base object of Python, so every new-style class (old style classes in Python 2 are exceptions) is a subclass of object, including type.  Since object is the base type, it is the subclass of nothing, hence the final False.

Comment: Another good read on this subject: http://www.cafepy.com/article/python_types_and_objects/python_types_and_objects.html

Comment: @AlanLeuthard That's not quite correct; not everything is a type: `isinstance(4, type)` returns `False`. It is true however that everything is an `object`. So `isinstance(x, object)` returns `True` no matter what `x` is. This implies that every type is a subclass of `object` and therefore `issubclass(type(x), object)` is `True` for all `x`. `type` on the other hand is the "ultimate" type of all objects. That is `isinstance(type(x), type)` is `True` for all `x`. Note that `issubclass(object, type)` is false for no particular reason but if it was true it would introduce a cycle in the `__mro__`.

Comment: @a_guest: (1)  "`isinstance(x, object)` returns True no matter what `x` is. This implies that every type is a subclass of `object`". I think that implies every type is an instance of `object` instead of a subclass of `object`, i.e. `object` is a metaclass of every type, correct? (2) Why "`isinstance(4, type)` returns False"?  `4` is an instance of `int`, and `int` is an instance of `type`, so `4` should be an instance of `type`, correct? (3) Does `builtins.isinstance(type, object)` and `builtins.isinstance(object, type)` both being true introduce a cycle somewhere?

Comment: @Tim (1) Both claims are true (check via `all(map(lambda x: issubclass(x, object), filter(lambda x: isinstance(x, type),__builtins__.__dict__.values())))` or `all(map(lambda x: issubclass(type(x), object), __builtins__.__dict__.values()))` for example; usually for `x` being an instance of `y`, `type(x)` is a subclass of `y` though there are other means such as `abc.ABCMeta.register` or overriding `__instancecheck__`), however `object` is not a metaclass it just happens that `type` is an instance of `object` as it is the case for all "objects" (which is achieved at the implementation level).

Comment: @Tim (...1) It's better (and more accurate) to phrase it the other way round: if `type(x)` is a subclass of `y` then `x` is an instance of `y`. (2) Such relations hold for subclasses but inferring the type of an object implies going one step "up" in the hierarchy. Let's consider the following (real-world) example: a specific book is an instance of "Book" and "Book" itself is an instance of "Publisher" (which creates "Book"s, probably along some "Journal"s, ...). But that doesn't mean that the specific book is a publisher. Class inheritance and class instantiation are different in that sense.

Comment: @Tim (3) No, those relations hold for consistency reasons. When it comes to attribute lookup however then inheritance is of importance (subclass checks). The method resolution order (`__mro__`) of an object is deciding how the name of an attribute is resolved. Python refuses to introduce cyclic dependencies here (see also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2223343/3767239)). Also for `abc.ABCMeta.register` (which doesn't make the class enter the `__mro__`) it is forbidden because there's no sensible way of interpreting such situations (apart from the `object`/`type` starting point).

Comment: @a_guest: Thanks! (1) Is it correct that If class `A`  is an instance of class `B`,  then `B` is a metaclass of `A`, so `object` and `type` are instances of each other, i.e. metaclasses of each other? (2) We can access attributes of a class, via its instances, so does it make sense that an instance can reuse the attributes of its class? So [for class `A` to reuse class `B`, when shall I make `B` a superclass of `A`, and when `B` a metaclass of `A`?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44880211/156458)

Comment: @Tim (1) Almost, I'd rephrase it a bit: if class `A` is an instance of class `B` then `B` is the type of `A` _and_ `B` is a metaclass. A metaclass is just a class whose instances are classes themselves. `type(object)` is `type` again (thus `object` is a direct instance of `type`) but `type(type)` is also `type`. However `issubclass(type, object)` is true ( `type.__mro__` is `(<class 'type'>, <class 'object'>)`) and thus `type` is considered an instance of `object`. Think about it as follows: `isinstance(type, object)` checks `issubclass(type(type), object)` and `type(type)` is `type`.

Comment: @Tim (2) Yes, objects can refer to their class'es attributes. It happens (roughly) as follows: `x.a` calls `x.__getattr__('a')` which checks if `'a' in x.__dict__` (the attribute namespace of the object `x`). If not then it considers the attribute namespace of all classes defined in `x.__mro__`, starting with `x.__class__`. Instead of thinking in terms of classes it's better to think in terms of objects (keeping this lookup chain in mind). Usually you will operate on objects that are not classes themselves (like the number `42`) and thus have no access to the metaclass's attributes.

Comment: @Tim (...2) Class attributes are useful if they are considered the same for each instance (they are shared among all instances). Metaclasses are very useful for modifying (or extending) the class instantiation process. They have access to all bases that were defined as well as to all attributes. For example [`django`](https://www.djangoproject.com/) makes use of metaclasses for turning the user's model definitions into database hooks. If you define a class attribute `DateField('date')` for example then `django` replaces this with an object that lets you access your database accordingly.

Comment: Thanks. @a_guest  in (1), "However `issubclass(type, object)` is true ( `type.__mro__` is `(<class 'type'>, <class 'object'>)`) and thus `type` is considered an instance of `object.` "  do you mean `isinstance(type, object)` by `issubclass(type, object)`?

Comment: @Tim I mean the following; let `x` be an object and `y` a class object. Then the following relation holds: from `issubclass(type(x), y)` follows `isinstance(x, y)`. And thus because `issubclass(type(type), object) -> issubclass(type, object)` follows `isinstance(type, object)`.

Comment: @a_guest: I see what you meant. Thanks. Are there other languages which have similar things to`type` and `object` in Python? Did Python borrow the ideas of `type` and `object` from other languages, and are the ideas not uncommon in language designs?

Comment: @Tim As far as I know the design of Python was much influenced by [Smalltalk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smalltalk). However object-oriented programming languages in general feature the notion of objects, classes and metaclasses. [Ruby](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ruby_(programming_language)) is a good example, but even Java has the concept of a metaclass [`Class`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html) which is the type of all classes.

Comment: @a_guest: Thanks. "however `object` is not a metaclass it just happens that `type` is an instance of `object`". Since everything (including any class and specific type) is an instance of `object`, isn't `object` a metaclass?

Comment: @Tim No, `object` is not a metaclass. The deciding relations are the following (speaking of Python 3): every class is a subclass of `object`, including metaclasses and also `type`. In addition from `issubclass(type(x), y)` follows that `isinstance(x, y)`. Therefore `isinstance(x, object)` is `True` for all `x` (note that `type(type) is type`). Nevertheless `type` is the ultimate metaclass, although `object` takes the last position in each metaclass's `__mro__`.

Comment: @a_guest Thanks. If I understand correctly, `type` is a metaclass, because any class and specific type is an instance of `type`.  According to your proof,  any class and specific type is an instance of `object`. Why isn't `object` a metaclass for the same reason for `type` being a metaclass?

Comment: @Tim In OOP everything has a type (is an instance of that type) and so we need something to instantiate class objects. This is where `type` comes into play. `type` is the type which is used to instantiate all other types. In Python 3 it has been decided that everything shall be an object (this is not the case for Python 2 !), including `type`, for consistency reasons. So `object` is the ultimate type (object) in the `__mro__` of each object. `object` is not a metaclass however because it doesn't implement the required functionality - this is what we have `type` for already.

Comment: tbh this question is much better than it has been recognised. I think it enlightens a lot about Python metaclasses.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The instance relation between type and object in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69861244/the-instance-relation-between-type-and-object-in-python)