# The instance relation between type and object in python?

Tags: python-3.x, object, types, instance

Show class relation between type and object:

```
issubclass(type,object)
True
issubclass(object,type)
False
```

It is clear that `type` derived from `object`,`object` is the father class of `type`,`type` is the son `class` of `object`.

```
isinstance(type,object)
True
isinstance(object,type)
True
```

How to understand that `type` is the instance of `object` and vice versa ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Useful Definition

**isinstance**(object, classinfo)

> Return `True` if the *object* argument is an instance of the *classinfo* argument, or of a (direct, indirect or virtual) subclass thereof.
>
>  https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/functions.html?highlight=isinstance#isinstance

### 1) `type` is an instance of `object`

- All data is represented by objects and `object` is a base for all classes

> Objects are Python’s abstraction for data. All data in a Python program is represented by objects or by relations between objects.
>
>  https://docs.python.org/3.9/reference/datamodel.html#types

> `object` is a base for all classes.
>
> https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/functions.html?highlight=object#object

- `type` inherits from `object` (https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/functions.html?highlight=object#type) so `type` is both a subclass and also an instance of `object` using the `isinstance` description.

### 2) `object` is an instance of `type`

- `object` is a type object. In other words, `object` is of type, `type`

> Type Objects
>
> Type objects represent the various object types. An object’s type is accessed by the built-in function `type()` 
> https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=subclass#type-objects

- `type(object)  # returns type`
- `type(type)  # returns type`
- `object.__class__  # returns type`
- `type.__class__  # returns type`
- Which helps us understand how `isInstance(object, type)` will return `True`.
- ***An intuitive way to think about this is that the `object` object is of type `type` but `object` is not a subclass of `type` because it doesn't inherit from `type`***