# Python relation between object and type

Tags: python, class, types

After sometimes spent on writing small Python scripts, I started to try to learn it more formally.

I've this code :

```
class One(object):
    
    pass

print(One, type(One))


class Two(type):
    
    pass

print(Two, type(Two))

print(object , type(object))

print(type, type(type))

print(isinstance(type , type))

print(isinstance(object , type))

print(isinstance(type , object))
```

output:

```
<class '__main__.One'> <class 'type'>
<class '__main__.Two'> <class 'type'>
<class 'object'> <class 'type'>
<class 'type'> <class 'type'>
True
True
True
```

And all of a sudden I feel like I wasted my time , why both `object` and `type` if they look the same. I try to dig more:

```
ob_list = [i for i in dir(object)]
print(ob_list)
print(object.__mro__)
print(object.__base__) ## How do I get this __base__ not in dir(object) !!!
print(object.__class__)
print('\n\n')

ty_list = [i for i in dir(type)]
print(ty_list)
print(type.__mro__)
print(type.__base__)
print(type.__class__)

print('\n\n')
print(object == type)
print(type(object) == type(type))
print(object == type)
```

output:

```
['__class__', '__delattr__', '__dir__', '__doc__', '__eq__', '__format__', '__ge__', '__getattribute__', '__getstate__', '__gt__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__init_subclass__', '__le__', '__lt__', '__ne__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__']
(<class 'object'>,)
None
<class 'type'>


['__abstractmethods__', '__annotations__', '__base__', '__bases__', '__basicsize__', '__call__', '__class__', '__delattr__', '__dict__', '__dictoffset__', '__dir__', '__doc__', '__eq__', '__flags__', '__format__', '__ge__', '__getattribute__', '__getstate__', '__gt__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__init_subclass__', '__instancecheck__', '__itemsize__', '__le__', '__lt__', '__module__', '__mro__', '__name__', '__ne__', '__new__', '__or__', '__prepare__', '__qualname__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__ror__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasscheck__', '__subclasses__', '__subclasshook__', '__text_signature__', '__weakrefoffset__', 'mro']
(<class 'type'>, <class 'object'>)
<class 'object'>
<class 'type'>


False
True
False
```

Seems to me, please correct me if am I wrong , probably I am, that `type` inherits from `object` but why `type(object)` is `'type'` and not `'object'`

Comment: got the duplicate link , but I like this one too https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69861244/the-instance-relation-between-type-and-object-in-python The instance relation between type and object in python?